# Multiple Javascript files creating alert boxes

Tags: javascript, alert

I have been given a project - the one HTML page includes about 45 different javascript files. I am getting alert boxes when I click on some of the elements - which javascript file is making the alert? How do I determine this, preferably which line in the javascript file but I can start with which file...

If this can be done within the web browser (I dont care which web browser) please let me know how... I have looked at the resources tab in chrome but it did not help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Tried searching for the text in the alert-box while in 'Resources' tab? (works for me fine)

Comment: The popups have no text in them, I'm using Notepad++... I've looked through a lot of them but cannot tell where these blank popups are coming from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your own javascript file on top of the page and predefine alert with:

```
alert = function(msg) {
     alert(msg); // put breakpoint here
}
```

Then use the debugger (Firebug in Firefox, or Developer Tools in Chrome) to put breakpoint as described above. The stack trace view in the debugger will show you which script line / file is creating the alert

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor to replace all

```
alert
```

by

```
console.log
```

And then use [Chrome inspector](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to see where the logs are.

Comment: Yes but that wouldn't say him which alert he sees. And if he has no text editor... then maybe SO is not the place to ask...

Comment: Either way. The most important is to use a good js tool like Chrome inspector after that. But in the end, he will be better with console.log than with alerts... alerts are a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Use the profiler in Firebug

Console -> Profile -> Click to enable. It will show which all functions are calling, search that function names, and add break points to debug.